# systemctl status active: exited vs running

Tags: systemd, services

Sorry for this noob question, I searched for it and found no explanation.

I'm unable to understand the different of systemctl status `active (exited)` for `active (running)`. Here are 2 examples on my server:

```
$systemctl status pihole-FTL.service
● pihole-FTL.service - LSB: pihole-FTL daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/pihole-FTL; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2020-12-31 12:21:34 -03; 1h 13min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 38279)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/pihole-FTL.service

dez 31 12:21:34 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: pihole-FTL daemon...
dez 31 12:21:34 server pihole-FTL[81286]: Not running
dez 31 12:21:34 server su[81306]: (to pihole) root on none
dez 31 12:21:34 server su[81306]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user pihole by (uid=0)
dez 31 12:21:34 server su[81306]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user pihole
dez 31 12:21:34 server systemd[1]: Started LSB: pihole-FTL daemon.



$systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-12-31 11:55:36 -03; 1h 40min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 35401 (apache2)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 38279)
     Memory: 36.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─ 35401 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 35402 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 35404 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 35405 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 35406 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 38219 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 38221 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 82281 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─ 82286 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─148242 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─188358 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

dez 31 11:55:36 server systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
dez 31 11:56:57 server sudo[38106]: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/stuff/www/html/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/pihole status web
dez 31 11:56:57 server sudo[38106]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
dez 31 11:56:57 server sudo[38106]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
dez 31 11:57:00 server sudo[38216]: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/stuff/www/html/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/pihole status web
dez 31 11:57:00 server sudo[38216]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
dez 31 11:57:00 server sudo[38216]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
dez 31 12:22:01 server sudo[82205]: www-data : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/stuff/www/html/admin ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/pihole status web
dez 31 12:22:01 server sudo[82205]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

I tested and both daemons are running properly, why then is pihole exited?

Answer (score 6):

The pi-hole job is not a .service that systemd monitors.

It's just a script that launches the daemon. That's a very 2005 way of doing things (systemd did not exist before 2010)

- Here's the clue: The pi-hole job is located in `/etc/init.d/`, which is the standard location to put sysvinit scripts. It's NOT located in `/lib/systemd/system/` or `/etc/systemd/system/`, which are the standard locations for systemd .service files.

Systemd has no idea that a daemon is being launched by the script. It only knows that the script exited successfully.

There's nothing wrong with your method of launching pi-hole. The older and newer ways can co-exist peacefully. It merely means that you're not using systemd features (like monitoring and respawning). Alternately, your favorite search engine will happily show you systemd .service-based ways of launching pi-hole.

Comment: tnx! So, scripts using init.d are exited, while systemd scripts remain running?

Comment: No. Scripts are scripts (not services). Services are services (not scripts). Use the correct word to describe each. You will avoid confusing yourself that way. If you don't understand what a *systemd service* or legacy *sysvinit script* really are, then look them up.